Deleting the role from instance profile throwing access denied error
I have below code which deletes the inline policy, managed policy and the role it self from the IAM.
For this I have created a role with following custom policies attached to it.
STS
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/*"
        }
    ]
}

IAM -
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:policy/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

My Code is as below
 self.iam_client = boto3.client('iam', verify=False)
    math_role_name = f"MathRole-{userId}-role"
        logger.info(f"Deleting the policies and math role {math_role_name} for test user ")
        # response = iam_client.delete_role(roleName=math_role_name)
        response = self.iam_client.list_role_policies(RoleName=math_role_name)
        for inline_policy in response['PolicyNames']:
            logger.info(f"deleting inline policy: {inline_policy}")
            delete_inline_policy_response = self.iam_client.delete_role_policy(
                RoleName=math_role_name,
                PolicyName=inline_policy
            )
            logger.info(f"deleted inline policy response {delete_inline_policy_response}")
        attached_policies = self.iam_client.list_attached_role_policies(RoleName=math_role_name)
        for items in attached_policies['AttachedPolicies']:
            logger.info(f"detaching the attached policy : {items['PolicyArn']}")
            detach_inline_policy_response = self.iam_client.detach_role_policy(
                RoleName=math_role_name,
                PolicyArn=items['PolicyArn']
            )
            logger.info(f"deleted managed policy response {detach_inline_policy_response}")
        logger.info(f"list instance profile for the role")
        instance_profile = self.iam_client.list_instance_profiles_for_role(
            RoleName=math_role_name
        )
        logger.info(
            f"deleting instance profile for role {math_role_name} :{instance_profile['InstanceProfiles'][0]['InstanceProfileName']}")
        delete_role_from_instance_profile = self.iam_client.remove_role_from_instance_profile(
            InstanceProfileName=instance_profile['InstanceProfiles'][0]['InstanceProfileName'],
            RoleName=math_role_name
        )
        delete_instance_profile = self.iam_client.delete_instance_profile(
            InstanceProfileName=instance_profile['InstanceProfiles'][0]['InstanceProfileName']
        )
        logger.info(f"deleting role : {math_role_name}")
        delete_role = self.iam_client.delete_role(
            RoleName=math_role_name
        )
        logger.info(f"deleted role response {delete_role}")

However When I run with with my role it throws following error
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/Role-devops-QA-GithubActions/GitHub_to_AWS_via_FederatedOIDC is not authorized to perform: iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile on resource: instance profile MathRole-xxxxxxx-role because no identity-based policy allows the iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile action

Any idea what policy I need to attach to the role so that it can delete the role from instance profile
Tried following searches but no luck--
How to remove the intance profile role while delete the role.
What policy I need to attach to my role to delete instance profile role.
Instance profile deletion throws an error.
